# QGIS transform coordinates (to_dm)

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I want to transform x-coordinates into dddmm.mm. When I use an expression like `to_dm($x, 'x', 2)` I am getting something like in the screenshot. This is obviously not correct. What am I doing wrong?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data seems to be in 3857, which is expressed in meters. The formula is then trying to format this webmercator coordinate as degree-minute. Since the input coordinate is > 360, the coordinate is "wrapped" around the earth, generating the garbish result.

To display the lat-long coordinates, the formula should first reproject the point from 3857 to 4326, and then format it

```
to_dm(x(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326' )), 'x', 2)
```